# Rmd to PDF compiling error: Package geometry \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing a paper in R markdown and need to format it with [this .cls file](http://cljournal.org/Docs/clv3.cls) supplied by an academic journal.

A minimal .tex file compiles perfectly well with the above cls file.

My .tex file (compiled on ShareLaTeX with `clv3.cls` saved in same directory):

```
\documentclass[shortpaper]{clv3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Paper title}
\author{Name Surname}
\date{May 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

However a comparable minimal document in R markdown, using the same cls file, fails to compile in Rstudio, with the following error: `! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.`

My Rmd file (with `clv3.cls` file saved in same directory):

```
---
title: "Paper title"
author: "Name Surname"
documentclass: clv3
classoption: shortpaper
output: pdf_document
---

# Introduction

Some text.
```

Why is this error induced when I try to use this class file with an R markdown document and how may I fix it?

I've tried manually specifying a pagewidth setting in the YAML header, but I don't really know what I'm doing. This seems undesirable anyway, since the normal LaTeX document works fine without it (and surely page width is something that should be specified by a journal, not manually overwritten by an author).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know where exactly the `clv3.cls` class and the default `pandoc` template clash. However, that template does so many things that do not make sense when writing with a specific style, that is best to use your own template. Using `clv3-template.tex`

```
\documentclass[shortpaper]{clv3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

$if(title)$
  \title{$title$}
$else$
  \title{}
$endif$
$if(author)$
  \author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \\ $endfor$}
$else$
  \author{}
$endif$

\begin{document}

$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$

$body$

\end{document}
```

together with

```
---
title: "Paper title"
author: "Name Surname"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    template:
      clv3-template.tex
---

# Introduction

Some text.
```

should be a good starting point.

Comment: In case your template needs modifying, it may be worth noting that the default ones are stored in `system.file("rmd/latex", package = "rmarkdown")`; there are different versions for different pandoc versions.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works perfectly for the minimal example presented. However it breaks again pretty quickly as the document is made more complex (for example, inserting a bibliography and in-text citations). I'd like to expand a little on my solution for the potential benefit of any future readers, as I found it a bit of steep learning curve:

The issue here is that Pandoc has a LaTeX template, which it uses to produce PDF documents. This is separate from a .cls class file, which defines a document class. Like Ralf Stubner says, something about my particular class file was not cooperating with Pandoc's default template. This is probably super basic and obvious to many, but I had not appreciated this extra step nor understood the distinction between these files.

If one does not wish to deal with raw LaTeX, it seems there are quite a few templates out there for various kinds of documents (see, for example, the rticle package). Using R Markdown to produce a PDF document in a particular custom format (such as for a particular journal) will require construction of a LaTeX template, however. This can be done by either of two ways:

1. Tinkering with an existing template until you get what you need, either by finding Pandoc's default template and starting from there (see comment by user2554330 for location) or by cloning someone else's template on Github etc.
2. Writing a template from scratch. In this case, Ralf Stubner's minimal example above plus [this section](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#using-variables-in-templates) of the Pandoc manual will be informative.

In my case, I went with the latter option. I have saved my eventual template as [an R package](https://github.com/JaydenM-C/CLtemplate) which can be installed using `devtools::install_github("JaydenM-C/CLtemplate")`. So if anyone else would ever like to author a document for *Computational Linguistics* using this particular document style, this may save you some time.