# bookdown: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

I know that "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
" solution is in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279964/option-clash-for-package-hyperref
I used another tex template 'sjtuthesis.cls', which has used package `hyperref` as,

```
./sjtuthesis.cls:83:\RequirePackage[xetex, bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks, urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
```

But bookdown will add package `hyperref` automately, too. 
In generated bookdown.tex file by https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/tree/master/inst/examples

```
./_book/bookdown.tex:25:\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
./_book/bookdown.tex:26:\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color} % color is loaded by hyperref
```

so the two lines hyperref clash. 
I mean, how to avoid packages clash between custom tex template with bookdown inner-used package?
How to modify the rmd file? can anyone help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it happens quite often that a given class does not work well together with the default LaTeX template used by `rmarkdown`. You have to write your own template, c.f. [Rmd to PDF compiling error: Package geometry \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227885/rmd-to-pdf-compiling-error-package-geometry-paperwidth-0-0pt-too-short).

Comment: I knew the reason. I had `template:null` in *_out.yaml*.

Comment: I knew the reason. I had set `template:null` in *_out.yaml*. So rmarkdown use default.tex which include '\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}'. I just need write my own template.tex instead of the default.tex. it now works, thank you.

Comment: this is nuts. how can RMarkdown claim "it works right out of the box" and then fail to compile with it's *own* template?

Comment: @invictus R Markdown works out of the box using the default LaTeX classes. Custom LaTeX classes can be *very* different. I don't find it surprising that the default template, which is actually provided by `pandoc`, cannot cope with all of them.